# Template in C++ with raw type

Tags: c++, templates

In Java, we can do something like this:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
// Notice that String is not mentioned in the first declaration of array
```

**AS OPPOSED TO**

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

How can we something in similar in C++?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> array;`

Comment: In much the same way. What have you tried ?

Comment: A raw type is name of a generic class or interface without any type arguments that has been passed in.

Comment: @PaulR I have tried but i get `argument list missing`

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. Why do you need this? What are you trying to do later on that requires the template argument to be removed?

Comment: No, C++ doesn't do that. However you can (in C++11) say `auto x = std::vector<std::string>;`.

Comment: This is possible now since C++17. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in exactly the way you've written.

What you can do is one of the following, depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish:

- In C++11, you can use `auto` to automatically adapt to the type:  `auto = new ArrayList<String>();`.  This doesn't give you polymorphism, but it does save you typing the typename on the left hand side.
- If you want polymorphism, you can add a level to your class hierarchy, and make the left-hand side point to a parent class.

Here's an example of the second approach:

```
class IArrayList   // define a pure virtual ArrayList interface
{
     // put your interface pure virtual method declarations here
};

template <typename T>
class ArrayList : public IArrayList
{
     // put your concrete implementation here
};
```

Then, you could say in your code:

```
IArrayList* arrayList1 = new ArrayList<string>();
IArrayList* arrayList2 = new ArrayList<double>();
```

...and so on.

Comment: Bad advice. You cannot provide a working definition of `IArrayList`. It is by necessity either an empty interface, or one that moves typechecking to run-time, i.e. the opposite of what is required from a class template.

Comment: It has given me an idea :P

Comment: @n.m.:  Yes, I was suggesting `IArrayList` be a pure virtual interface.  The template `class ArrayList` defines a family of classes that implement that interface, but provide specialized implementations.  The interface class enforces the commonality of interface only.  How does this move type-checking to run time?  It just relies on good old virtual dispatch to do the right thing.  You still only have one implementation, albeit a templated implementation in the template class.

Comment: @n.m. : I made a minor edit above to make it clear I'm suggesting a pure virtual interface for IArrayList.  As long as there's only one implementation in the template `class ArrayList`, I think this solves the situation cleanly.  If you need to have a broader range of classes adhering to this interface, then you could have a more generic `ArrayListImpl` class that they all privately inherit (or have an instance of) to implement some common guts, or the like.

Comment: @n.m. : Ok, I think it clicked for me what you're getting at:  You can't define anything dependent on `T` (the template parameter) as part of the interface.  Got it.  That's not a problem for certain kinds of template classes, but it's a bad problem for templatized container classes, such as `ArrayList` might be, because it's not obvious how to get items into / out-of the container without some other shenanigans.

Comment: In Java the type of LHS is deduced from that of RHS at compile time. Your second suggestion is as far from that as it gets (i.e. not related at all).

Comment: @n.m. : If it's just a simple assignment as shown, then yes, I agree.  If there's more encapsulation involved (eg. a parameter to a constructor of a class that's going to hold the constructed thing in a member without knowing exactly what it is, or another level of container that will hold multiple variants of the template class), then `auto` won't work.  You need something polymorphic.  This goes back to one of the other comments that this feels like an XY problem, and I was considering two different scenarios for X.

Answer (score 2):

In c++， you can not use `vector array = new vector<string>()`, but in c++11, you can use `auto` keyword: `auto p = new vector<string>()`, it is the same as `vector<string> *p = new vector<string>()`.Hope that my answer can help you.